# Erlang bindings for CUDA or OpenCL

Tags: erlang, cuda, scalability, opencl

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213337/how-do-i-make-an-already-written-concurrent-program-run-on-a-gpu-array) on Erlang and CUDA, it is rather old so I would like to learn if something has changed since this question was posted. I would like to know if there is any  implementation of CUDA/OPENCL bindings for Erlang?

In general, I investigate if it is possible to scale ERLANG program vertically to GPU using CUDA/OPENCL to process a data stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL is here: https://github.com/tonyrog/cl
(You should use the nif branch if that isn't merged to master yet)

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. Last time I investigated this topic there was an issue with a high cost of the memory transfer from and to GPU. Is it still an issue?

Comment: Hi Skarab. Yes, it is still an issue, and will continue due to the nature of GPUs and how they are integrated into the bus.

Answer (score 3):

I'd wait for this talk http://erlang-factory.com/conference/SFBay2011/speakers/KevinSmith (they will upload video & slides after the conference)

Comment: Do you know where to find a video, because presentation slides are not very informative?

Answer (score 2):

I gave the talk Yurii mentioned and I'm not sure when the videos will be available. The code I demoed is available here: http://github.com/kevsmith/pteracuda. It's minimal but should illustrate what's possible with CUDA and NIFs. I'm hoping to improve it further once my machine arrives back home from SF.

Comment: Thx :). Could you provide a short information on a difference between your approach and https://github.com/tonyrog/cl? If you would like to provide a longer description I could start another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at https://github.com/vascokk/NumEr

I've been using bit from both this project and Smith's project.